# Recursive bash linux script

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

is it possible to assign the value of a call to a recursive script, to a variable?
Here is my code, the error says that on line 10: RIS = 2*1... 3*2 etc
That seems good work, but RIS is not assigned to a real value.

```
DECR=$1

if [[ ${DECR} -gt 0 ]] ; then
    echo ${DECR}
    ((DECR2 = ${DECR}-1))
    ((RIS = ${DECR} * `./fattoriale1.sh ${DECR2}`))
else
    ((RIS=1))
fi

echo ${RIS}

Error: ./fattoriale1.sh: riga 9: ((: RIS = 2 * 1
1: errore di sintassi nell'espressione (il token dell'errore è "1")
./fattoriale1.sh: riga 9: ((: RIS = 3 * 2
2: errore di sintassi nell'espressione (il token dell'errore è "2")
./fattoriale1.sh: riga 9: ((: RIS = 4 * 3
6: errore di sintassi nell'espressione (il token dell'errore è "6")
12
```

Thanks.

Comment: @123, not so. This is perfectly legal: ``echo $(( `echo 42` - `false; echo $?` ))``

Comment: @glennjackman That isn't `(())` it's `$(())`. Actually looks like both can. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 echo statements in your function, so if DECR > 0 then the output of the function contains a newline. The error message indicates you're trying to execute:

```
((RIS = 2 * 1
1))
```

Remove `echo $DECR` or change it to print to stderr: `echo $DECR >&2`

Comment: Thanks, it works. I really didn't know how to do, that echo was only a check output.
Another question: is there a way to write the same scipt using only one DECR variable instead of two?

Comment: yes: `factorial () { local n=$1; [[ $n -eq 1 ]] && echo 1 || echo $(( n * $( factorial $((n-1)) ) )); }`